# Run js client side for client logic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

im building an app using Next.js and im facing a problem with my header component.

I have a menu that folds to an hamburger menu on mobile. I need to show and hide a blur for the whole page when the menu shows up. So im trying to do this with js logic. The problem im facing is that the logic gets executed on sever, but im not able to add client side logic, so the button on click never works.

The code is the following:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export default () => {
    const [showMenu, setShowMenu] = useState(false)
    function toggleMenu () {
        setShowMenu(!showMenu)
    }
    return (
      <>
        <nav id="header">
          <button onClick={toggleMenu}>X</button>
        </nav>
        { showMenu ? 
            <div style={{background: 'rgba(0,0,0,.5)'}}></div>
        : null
        }
      </>
  )
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone is having the same issue, the problem was on the _document.js file. It introduces some issues with the onclick handler. So if it is really necesary to modify the _document.js file, you should be aware of this.